# Can Sphinx source files be pushed to ReadTheDocs without a linked repository?

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm moving the Mercurial repositories for all my open-source projects to OSDN (OSDN.net) from Bitbucket because Bitbucket will soon drop support for Mercurial.  However, OSDN only supports SSH, not HTTPS, as a file exchange protocol, and ReadTheDocs does not support SSH URLs.  The ReadTheDocs public API allows builds to be triggered, but does not support any way to provide the source files with the build trigger.

Or any *documented* way, at least.  Does anybody know of a way to either push document source files to RTD with a build trigger, or connect an OSDN repository to RTD so that RTD can clone the source files itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSDN does support both SSH & HTTP(S), for "writing" the only option is ssh. However, read-the-docs needs only to 'read'; https is fine (And supported, although a bit hard to find).

On OSDN, **toggle the *"RO*|*r/w" button***, to see the other-URL. It's not a button, nor trigger; but it looks like it *--The UX/UI design isn't very great ...*

Copy that RO value (again: ignore the UI-feedback. You can copy the https-URL. And past it on RTfD.

Note: for now, I could get *webhooks/integration* working. So, you have to go read-the-docs to rebuild, after a push. Or use the curl webhook from e.g a Makefile locally, see: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/webhooks.html#parameters

Comment: Thanks very much.  That was easy--but not obvious.